# How to get latest Tweets of an User

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to get my client latest tweets. After Searching in Google i got some code. Unfortunately the code is working in localhost, But not working in  the Hosting server. Its saying **couldn't find the server**. I am posting the code snapshot..

```
<?php

            function getTwitterStatus($userid){
            $url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=1";

            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("could not connect");

            foreach($xml->status as $status){
            $text = $status->text;
            }
            echo $text;
            }

            //my user id AmitEducation
            getTwitterStatus("AmitEducation");

            ?>
```

Please help me out. If anyone have better suggestion please help me.

Comment: mhm could you please check if your provider/hoster allows allow_url_fopen (phpinfo() should get this information) and/or must whitecard urls you are allowed to connect to (pretty often that is the case)

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing out the $url to make sure that it is what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), it's really awesome. And it's JSON. [+1]

```
$tweets = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=php&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed"));

foreach($tweets->results as $t){

  echo "Username: {$t->from_user_name}";
  echo "Tweet: {$t->text}" . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Please read the documentation for how to use and see examples.

Comment: can you give a simple example..how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

change the username in the link

```
    <?php
      $json = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/username.json?count=10", true); //getting the file content
      $decode = json_decode($json, true); //getting the file content as array
      print_r($decode);
    ?>
```

Comment: Returns: Sorry, that page does not exist

Comment: hmm changes in the twitter api